# ANSI C - how to read from stdin word by word?

Tags: c

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char i[50];
    while(scanf("%s ", i)){
        printf("You've written: %s \n", i);
    }
    printf("you have finished writing\n");

    return 0;
}
```

One problem is that the code doesn't do as it is expected to. If I typed in:

```
abc def ghi.
```

It would output:

```
You've written: abc
You've written: def
```

How can I fix it? The goal is to read every single word from stdin until it reaches "ENTER" or a "." (dot).

Comment: What about writing `scanf("%s")` once, then calling `scanf(" %s")` in the loop?

Comment: Leaving aside the problem, please use `scanf("%49s ", i)` in this instance to be in the habit of preventing buffer overruns. 'K?

Comment: Thanks but they didn't fix the problem. The thing is the while loop ends before reaching the last group of character, and this is not what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@cnicutar is pretty close, but you apparently only want to start reading at something other than white-space, and want to stop reading a single word when you get to whitespace, so for you scanset, you probably want something more like:

```
while(scanf(" %49[^ \t.\n]%*c", i)) {
```

In this, the initial space skips across any leading white space. The scan-set then reads until it gets to a space, tab, new-line or period. The %*c then reads (but throws away) the next character (normally the one that stopped the scan).

This can, however, throw away a character when/if you reach the end of the buffer, so you may want to use %c, and supply a character to read into instead. That will let you recover from a single word longer than the buffer you supplied.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
scanf("%49[ ^\n.]", str)
```

Or something like that.

Comment: This doesn't actually break on *spaces*, does it?

Comment: Just for my information... what does "%49[^\n.]" mean? Is it some regular expression pattern or something like that? Thanx!

Comment: @dmckee It doesn't. I was under the impression the op wants to read the entire line. Jerry Coffin has a better answer.

Comment: @nay: It's all in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf). Not a regular expression, but a character class.

Answer (score 2):

Ditch `scanf` altogether and go with `fgets`:

```
while (fgets(i, sizeof i, stdin))
{
  printf("you've written: %s\n", i);
}
```

with the following caveats:

1. If there's room in the target buffer, `fgets` will store the trailing newline as part of the input;
2. If you want to stop reading on finding a `.`, you'll have to add some logic to look for it in the input string, such as the following:

```
    int foundDot = 0;
    while (fgets(i, sizeof i, stdin) && !foundDot)
    { 
      char *dot = strchr(i, '.');
      char *newline = strchr(i, '\n');

      if (dot != NULL)
      {
        foundDot = 1;
        *dot = 0; // overwrite the '.' character with the 0 terminator
      }

      if (newline != NULL)
      {
        *newline = 0; // overwrite newline character with 0 terminator
      }

      /**
       * Assuming you don't want to print a blank line if you find a dot
       * all by itself. 
       */
      if (strlen(i) > 0) 
        printf("you've written: %s\n", i);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is with [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/). Otherwise you are repeating a bunch of difficult, complex work, and are likely to make mistakes.

Also, read [lex and yacc, 2nd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do).

Comment: Possible? Certainly. Easiest? Maybe not.

Comment: For this particular problem, that's sort of like using a jackhammer to hang a picture hook.

Comment: @JohnBode Perhaps, but I've found that every other "simple" solution ends up being more work, less effective, and full of subtle errors. Mainly because the problem moves beyond the toy/trivial initial problem set very quickly.