# Searching type char** for a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, search, char

Note that this is a repost, I have clarified my post to be more understandable

```
void searchArray(char ***array, int count){

    char * word = "";


    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fscanf(stdin, " ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%c", &word);
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(strcmp(word, (*array)[i]) == 0){
                    found = true;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if(found) printf("%s found!\n", word);
    else if (!found) printf("%s not found!\n", word);
}
```

In testing, the code returns " not found!" for every input.

The above is the code that I have for searching and traversing an array of type char ** ... I'm not sure whether I have my traversing logic wrong or if I'm improperly using strcmp... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for insertion which may help to clarify what exactly I'm trying to do:

```
int insertWord(char **array, int *count, char word[])
{
   char *wordPtr;

   wordPtr = (char *)malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char));
   if (wordPtr == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"    Malloc of array[%d] failed!\n", *count);
      return -1;
   }
   /* Memory for this word has been allocated, so copy characters
      and insert into array */

   strcpy(wordPtr, word);

   array[*count] = wordPtr;
   (*count)++;

   return 0;
}
```

My task is to search for a specific string in this data.

Comment: Are the strings from the `array` ending with `\0` ? I think your `fscanf(stdin, "%c", &word);` won't put `\0` at the end, and that might be the reason.

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17506236/2455888) first.

Comment: `fscanf(stdin, "%c", &something)` only reads *ONE CHARACTER*.  Are you sure you don't want something like `char word[80];` and `fscanf (%s%, word);`?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10148186/509868) question for reading words correctly from `stdin`

Comment: @haccks you posted that on my previous question. It is not helpful, this is for a lab and the insertion code is provided. I have to implement this using what they give me.

Comment: @Riptyde4; It was just for telling you that arrays are not pointers and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
void searchArray(char ***array, int count){

    char word[80];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fscanf(stdin, " ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", word);
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(strcmp(word, (*array)[i]) == 0){
                    found = true;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if(found) printf("%s found!\n", word);
    else if (!found) printf("%s not found!\n", word);
}
```

This code works perfectly. I think that since I was using fscanf(stdin, "%c", &word); it was reading in the open space character from the previous line (in the buffer) and then searching for it...is that how that works?

Thanks!

Comment: @haccks just as the link you posted states:  int arr[] is equivalent to int * arr, and you can access the elements using brackets in both.